# Delay increases sometimes when sending buffer via UDP socket

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I've developed an MPEG-ts Streamer. It reads the packets from a file and sends them at the right pace to the receiver.

Now everything works fine excluding that I have some lags quite often. I have searched for every possible error in my code. I have optimized my program quite a bit performance wise.

Now I keep a log with the time it takes the `sendto()` function to send the packet and I also log the difference between when the packet should have been sent and when it is sent.

I noticed that every time the packets are a lot later than average, the time it took the `sendto()` to send the previous packet is much higher than normal too.

This indicates me that it is the `sendto()` that is causing those lags every time it somehow takes longer to send a packet. I am using UDP sockets.

Am I maybe doing something wrong with the sockets? Could it be possible that the socket buffer is full and that it actually takes longer to send the packet? Or am I missing something? Is there maybe a way to accelerate the socket or to make it not fill it's buffer completely before sending?

As this is meant to stream video I am quite depending on the performance, mostly for HD where the lags happen more often as the amount of packets is much higher.

Comment: Do you get responses from your network peer or are you just sending and the peer is just receiving?

Comment: It's certainly possible that the send buffers are full, you should do some measurement of how much bandwidth you use , and how much you have available. It's likely help if you posted some of the timings you found, and a bit more about the amount and rate of data you're sending, packet sizes etc. Use wireshark to look at stuff too - you want to make sure you're not stuck on e.g. arp timeouts or triggering a lot of ICMP replys.  (And note that you lose UDP packets easily when the receiving buffers are full, but if the sending buffer is full, your program block.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only two reasons for `sendto()` to block:

- Your outgoing UDP buffer is full, and it needs to wait until space frees up
- The CPU scheduler simply decides to do something else for a while, as it can with any syscall.

Check the size of your outgoing buffer:

```
int buff_size;
int len = sizeof(buff_size);

err = getsockopt(s,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,(char*)&size,&len);
```

Some linux systems default to absurdly small send buffers (only a few kilobytes), so you may need to set it to something larger.

If buffer is larger and `sendto()` is briefly blocking anyway (how long exactly?) then that's probably just the cost of doing business.  Even on a LAN, and certainly on a WAN, latency is going to vary a lot.

**Update**

To increase the system limit on UDP buffer sizes:

```
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=1048576
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=1048576
```

You can make this permanent by adding the following lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.core.wmem_max=1048576
net.core.rmem_max=1048576
```

To take advantage of this within your application, you need to use `setsockopt()`:

```
int len, trysize, gotsize;
len = sizeof(int);
trysize = 1048576+32768;
do {
   trysize -= 32768;
   setsockopt(s,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,(char*)&trysize,len);
   err = getsockopt(s,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,(char*)&gotsize,&len);
   if (err < 0) { perror("getsockopt"); break; }
} while (gotsize < trysize);
printf("Size set to %d\n",gotsize);
```

Repeat the same thing for `SO_RCVBUF`.  The loop is important because many systems silently enforce a maximum which is less than the max you set with `sysctl` and when `setsockopt()` fails, it leaves the previous value untouched.  So you have to try many different values until you get one that sticks.  Its also important to not test for `(gotsize == trysize)` because on some systems the result which is set is not actually the same as the one you requested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question though. Is there a way to find the send buffer size on the linux shell?

Comment: You can find the upper bound (maximum a process is allowed to set) using `sysctl net.core.wmem_max` and `sysctl net.core.rmem_max`.  You can find the default using `sysctl net.core.wmem_default` and `net.core.rmem_default`. *However*, I have noticed that some linux systems exhibit quirks such not setting the exact value you request, setting a value which is twice or half what you request, or using bounds different that what sysctl says.  It seems to vary by kernel version and distribution, so expect the unexpected.

Comment: Thank you. My results are net.core.wmem_max = 131071 and net.core.wmem_default = 126976. Is that bytes? Is it big enough for HD streaming? Could that be the problem in my case?

Comment: That is bytes, that's the most common linux result, and in my opinion its not big enough to do anything of significant volume.  There's absolutely no reason for `_max` to be less than 1 megabyte.  `_default` should be left alone as low-volume processes don't need more, but high volume processes should be free to `setsockopt()` what they need.  Unfortunately, the only way to find out if the buffer size is causing problems in linux is to raise it and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you tell me how to raise that max value? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say without the code, but here are a few hints:

- It's possible that your code works just fine, and those delays are caused by OS scheduler.
- Usually, optimizing your code too early could actually lead to performance drops. Optimization is last step.

You can try to "nicer" your process. If this improves performance, it's an OS scheduler issue.

Comment: The optimisations I made were crutial as I wasn't correctly buffering the packets. Now after the optimisation it works perfectly except for thos occasional lags

Comment: That's not an optimization. That's a bug fix ;)

Comment: lol sorry guess you're right hehe :) Althoug a fixed program is always optimized :P

Comment: It's common for the problem to be caused by the scheduler. Linux default scheduling algorithm is not suitable for soft RT performance, and jitter is strongly related to it. You should use RT scheduling when forking or creating a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike TCP, UDP does not buffer data. Source code would definitively help to understand things better. How big are the packets you are sending? In UDP it would be best to keep the payload at the size of the MTU (1500 bytes)

Comment: Hi unfortunately I won't be able to post source code as I am not allowed to. I am sending MPEG-TS packets (188 Bytes) individually.

Comment: Not that it should explain your delay but 188 bytes is a bit low for the payload as the IP/UDP overhead becomes non-negligible. It might be better to introduce a bit more buffering and send at lest 3 or 4 MPEG packets per datagram

Comment: What I don't get is that working the way it does it works very well. It's really just sometimes that it takes the snedto longer to send the buffer but it then send s fast again.

Comment: Refering back to m0skit0's comment, using 188 bytes packets will generate a lot more system calls which might make your code more sensitive to occasional scheduler delays. In streaming, contrarily to videoconferencing, you are better off optimizing your network utilization by sending packets that are as close as possible to the MUT size

Comment: The OS/kernel certainly has socket buffers for both incoming and outgoing (UDP) packets. (There's no flow control though, so a slow receiver doesn't propagate back to the sender like with TCP.)

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** Replace the receiver with something that has a buffer. Or maybe try to send more data than the receiver really needs - it really should have a buffer already. I doubt that there is anyone in the world who builds set-top boxes **and** who doesn't know that there are network lags **and** who isn't bankrupt already.

From your explanation, I doubt that the cause is in your code. There are many reasons why it can be slower:

- The OS might decide to give another process control since you're doing I/O.
- The network buffer might be full
- The network might be congested
- The virus scanner might be interested in the same data that you're reading and steal too many cycles.
- If you're on Windows: The Aero desktop renders something (the IRQ of the graphics card usually has a higher priority than that of the network card).

Conclusion: Your problem is that the receiver has no buffer. There are really very many reasons that can cause a delay in the sending of the UDP packets and all of them are not under the control of your code.

---

*Original Answer*

UDP is not a reliable protocol. There is no guarantee that packets arrive at the receiver in time. UDP just has a smaller overhead than TCP but that comes at the cost of reliability.

The usual solution is to send more data than the client needs. So for example, you send the first 10 seconds at full throttle. This allows the client to cache some data to play over lags.

You should also change the client to send back the length of the cached stream to the server every few seconds. The server can then calculate how many packets to send at full throttle to keep the cache on the client side filled.

Comment: The problem is it's not a software client but a Set-top-box.
And the otehr thing is that this doesn't happen all the time. Its happening just occasionnaly and I don't get it why at some points the sendto() takes longer than usually

Comment: How do you know that `sendto()` takes longer? Did you measure it? How?

Comment: struct timespec stimeBefore;
struct timespec stimeAfter;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stimeBefore);


That's how I measured it
sendto(...);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stimeAfter);

fprintf(log,"Send time = %d\n",((((stimeAfter.tv_sec * 1000000000) + stimeAfter.tv_nsec) - ((stimeBefore.tv_sec * 1000000000) + stimeBefore.tv_nsec)) / 1000));